# Can I expose Unity scene as a webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine, ionic-framework, unityscript

I need to integrate Unity in my application.
Can I expose unity scene as a web service and use in my hybrid mobile app?
I create one zoom in zoom out functionality in unity. and need to call this functionality in hybrid app.
How is this possible?

I need to take picture from camera through my hybrid app and need to pass this image to unity and zoom in zoom out functionality will work ...
How is it possible?
How can expose my unity project as web service?

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Is that for android? then search: embed unity to existing android project

Comment: no its not android..hybrid app ..its ionic

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, you could use an HttpListener :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

I used that for a custom terminal to interact with my build.
Worked as expected.